# Trying to print a string in a qsort function

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble passing a valid value to the `qsort` function but can't quite figure out what's going wrong with it. Here is what I have so far:

```
int main(void)
{
    char* strings[4] = {"Onus", "deacon", "Alex", "zebra"};
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(strings));
    qsort(strings, 4, 8, scmp);
}

int scmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    printf("%s\n", (char*) p1);
    return 0;
    // ignore return value -- I'm just looking to print the string.
}
```

It just seems to print gibberish when I do this. Is this because `qsort` expects a value a pointer to a value and I'm passing it a pointer to a (char) pointer? What would be the correct way to reference it then?

It seems instead it should be: `printf("%s\n", *(char* const*) p1);` ? This is from some trial-and-error, though not sure why that works -- i.e., the `*(char**)`.

For example, for passing an `int` I can do:

```
const int *v1 = p1;
```

But then a `char*` needs to be:

```
const char *s1 = *(char* const *) p1;
```

Why not just `const char *s1 = (char*) p1;` ?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes I've updated the question -- I'm just looking how to pass the string / properly dereference the value.

Comment: Your `*(char* const*) p1` is correct. `p1, p2` are addresses of the elements of `strings[]`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica could you please elaborate that a bit please? For elements of the `strings[]` array wouldn't it just require a single dereference to get the string value?

Comment: You have an array of pointers to sort.  But what if it was an arrays of blobs (each blob being 1 Mbyte in size).  Would you expect the compare function to receive 2 _blobs_ or 2 addresses of   blobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strings` is an array of pointers to `char`.  The comparison function for `qsort` gets passed *pointers* to the two elements of the array that should be compared.  Since the elements of the array are pointers to `char`, the arguments `p1, p2` to `scmp` are pointers to (const) pointers to `char`, and should be cast to `char **` (or rather `char * const *`).

What needs to be passed to `printf` is the pointer to `char` itself, so you have to dereference the argument to get that pointer.  If you wanted to look at the individual characters of the string, you'd have to dereference again.  There are two `*`s in the name of the type, so you have to apply `*` two times to get back to the underlying primitive type.

```
printf("The first character of the string is %c\n", **(char * const *)p1);
```